# Elasticsearch field boost not showing up in mapping

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, tire

I have a model such as

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks

  mapping do
    indexes :id, index: :not_analyzed
    indexes :title, analyzer: 'snowball'
    indexes :hashtags, analyzer: 'keyword', type: :array, boost: 10
  end

....
end
```

My goal is to boost hits on `hashtag` over other fields in a `_all` lookup.

After I do an import, I use this endpoint to check the mapping-

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/videos/_mapping'
```

I get this response

```
{
    "videos": {
        "video": {
            "properties": {
                "created_at": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "dateOptionalTime"
                },
                "hashtags": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "id": {
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "title": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "updated_at": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "dateOptionalTime"
                },
                "video_id": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I notice that the mapping does not have a boost on the `hashtag` property. Am I missing anything here?

**Edit 1:**

If I do `Video.index.mapping_to_json`, it does give me the `:boost` for `hashtag` in the hash. But that isn't visible in ES after I import.

Comment: Generally, use query time boost unless you _really_ know what you're after.

Comment: @karmi - thanks! I think I will go with query time boost. But am also curious if I can have an index time boost setup via tire?

Comment: You have to delete the index and re-create it, or use `FORCE` with the Rake task.

Comment: @karmi -thanks! the `FORCE` trick worked. And thank you for the awesome gem, am a fan! If you could put an answer with that, I'd accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Karmi's suggestion did it for me.

> You have to delete the index and re-create it, or use FORCE with the Rake task
>
> -- Karmi

Answer (score 0):

You might have done your boost in the wrong way (Depends on how Tire does boost)  See this link: 
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-boost-field.html
Also I know Elasticsearch suggests boosting at query-time.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using query-time boost, but was just curious if I can get index boost setup via tire. Please see edit for further debug info.

Comment: yeah, in the mapping section:
indexes :name, :boost => 10